# when I updating my values a ReflectionException occurs

Tags: laravel

I want to update actualCost
**ProposalExpenses::where('EXPENSE_ID', '=', $request->id)
->update(['ACTUAL_EXPENSES' => $request->actualCost]);**

//this my function

```php
public function ProgrameLogExpUploadFiles(Request $request, $proposal_id) {

    $officer = officer::where('USER_LOGIN_LOGIN_ID', '=', Auth::user()->LOGIN_ID)->first();
    if (isset($request->id)) {
        ProposalExpenses::where('EXPENSE_ID', '=', $request->id)
            ->update(['ACTUAL_EXPENSES' => $request->actualCost]);

        if ($request->updated == "true" && $request->balance <= 0) {
            
            $old_files_db = \App\model\programme_proposal\ProgrammeExpenseFileUpload::where([
                'PROPOSAL_ID'=>$proposal_id,
                'EXPENCE_ID'=>$request->id
            ])->get();
                
          \App\model\programme_proposal\ProgrammeExpenseFileUpload::where([
                'PROPOSAL_ID'=>$proposal_id,
                'EXPENCE_ID'=>$request->id
            ])->delete();

          if(isset($old_files_db)){
              foreach ($old_files_db as $file) {
                  try {
                      \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::delete("programme_expenses/" . $file->STORAGE_FILE_NAME);
                  } catch (\Exception $e) {

                  }
              }
          }

        foreach ($request->file as $file) {
            $upload_success = $file->store('programme_expenses');

            if ($upload_success) {                        
         
         
        \App\model\programme_proposal\ProgrammeExpenseFileUpload::create([

            'STORAGE_FILE_NAME' => str_replace("programme_expenses/", "", $upload_success),
            'REAL_NAME' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
            'UPLOADED_DATE' => \Illuminate\Support\Carbon::now(),
            'UPLOADED_BY_STAFF_NIC' => $officer->NIC,
            'PROPOSAL_ID' => $proposal_id,
            'EXPENCE_ID' => $request->id
         ]);
           }
        }
    }
    if ($request->updated == "false" && $request->balance > 0) {
        $old_files_db = \App\model\programme_proposal\ProgrammeExpenseFileUpload::where(['PROPOSAL_ID'=>$proposal_id,'EXPENCE_ID'=>$request->id])->get();
                \App\model\programme_proposal\ProgrammeExpenseFileUpload::where(['PROPOSAL_ID'=>$proposal_id,'EXPENCE_ID'=>$request->id])->delete();
                if(isset($old_files_db)){
                    foreach ($old_files_db as $file) {
                        try {
                            \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::delete("programme_expenses/" . $file->STORAGE_FILE_NAME);
                        } catch (\Exception $e) {

                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code which is causing this error. If you just paste an error without the code how do you expect to get viable suggestions. Anyway the error shows `App\Http\Controllers\ProgramLogReportEditController does not exist` so check for namespace errors or whether the file exists

Comment: I edited my question .can you give me a solution now? ProgramLogReportEditController file is already exists.How I check namespace errors?? can you explain??As well as this issue comes only in the live environment. Not in the QA environment and UAT environment

Comment: If it works on local or other server and doesn't work only on live server then you can try running `composer dump-autoload` to refresh the autoloader. However the namespaces like `\App\model\programme_proposal\ProgrammeExpenseFileUpload` seem a bit off to me

Comment: "\App\model\programme_proposal\ProgrammeExpenseFileUpload " ,this is for upload expenses files.if the actual cost of expenses is greater than the cost of the approved expenses, the user must upload a file to prove that. However, thank u and I will try your solution.